# Подключение к MySQL клиентом, как спрятать пароль?

Tags: база-данных, java, защита

Вообщем есть мобильное приложение, которое подключается к MySQL грубо говоря вот так:

> Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?user=root&password=pwd");

как защитить логин и пароль, ведь можно декомпилировать исходник приложения и достать логин и пароль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать API на стороне сервера, через это API мобильные клиенты будут общаться с базой.
Можно использовать API с авторизацией, можно использовать API без авторизации, но с ключами. Тут уже на ваш выбор.

API делается довольно просто. Например, вам нужно получить список пользователей вашего сервиса. Самый простой способ - сделать веб-приложение, которое будет отдавать данные в xml, или json.

Клиент посылает в api запрос, типа: http://apiserv/app_id/clients.get?sig_key=<somehashhere>
Сервер получив этот запрос возвращает ответ:

[
{"name": "Vasya", "id":"1"},
{"name": "Sidor", "id":"2"},
]

Ваш клиент парсит этот ответ, и далее выполняет какие-то нужные вам действия. И так далее.

Мы у себя сделали так:

Написали на питоне с использованием cherrypy класс, который обрабатывает входящие запросы, и мапит их на классы-обработчики. Т.е., он смотрит наличие аргумента cmd. Дальше в списке известных ему команд ищет команду, которая пришла в виде значения аргумента. Если команда найдена, запускается ее обработчик, которому на вход поступают остальные аргументы. Кстати, забыл отметить, что перед тем, как начинается поиск соответствующего обработчика, у нас происходит проверка доступа по ключу. Т.е., каждому клиенту выдается id приложения, и sig_key, которым клиент подписывает каждый запрос. Проще говоря, создает хэш запроса. По app_id мы можем идентифицировать приложение, и узнать его ключ на стороне сервера. Сервер при получении запроса так-же, при получении этого запроса создает хэш  запроса, и сравнивает его с пришедшим. Получился такой своеобразный apiserv, через который мы можем обращаться сразу к нескольким базам.

Есть вариант проще. Например, можно использовать фреймворк Yii для создания api. Получается довольно быстро и удобно.

Answer (score 4):

Обращение к самой базе **должно идти на стороне сервера**, а не со стороны клиента, например крутится прилага на томкате которая обрабатывает запросы от вашего клиента возвращая ему данные из базы, **иначе в любом случае вам придется хронить логин пароль** пусть даже и в зашифрованом виде. надеюсь что вы сами понимаете что это не айс)).

Comment: не подскажите с чего начать написание этой прилаги?) т.е. как я понял пишется своеобразное API для обращения в базу (авторизация, запросы и т.п.) которое реализуется в этом приложении?

Comment: @romanew, для Вас ответил @nolka достаточно развернуто, но --

API - это не просто звук взял и сделал. должен на серваке крутится в простейшем случае сервлет который будет мапить запросы и возвращать положеные ответы. кароче я бы юзал SpringFramework

для примера - https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example
просто скачайте разархивируйте, установите maven, запустите в корне разархивированого каталога команду mvn install , у вас все соберется затем установите tomcat и закиньте варки полученые в предыдущем действии в каталог webapps томката. и наслаждайтесь

Comment: ко всему этому делу потом прикручивается gson, просто добавлением одной либы или прописываение dependensy в файл pom проекта который вы будете юзать. появятся вопросы или будут проблемы на любом из этих этапов пишите на хэшкод, разберемся)))